# HTML5 drop down option have to be by default

Tags: html, css, class, attributes

i m trying to do a HTML5 question in that i have to make a drop down option selected by default.

i tried to use the attribute "required" and "default"... bt still not working.d "default"... bt still not working.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is for a drop-down option to be selected by default and the solution is the following.

Using `selected`

```html
    <label>Choose an option:</label>
    <select>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2" selected>Option 2 (Selected by default)</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```